# How to get 2 value from 1 radio button on laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, radio-button, laravel-blade

I am stuck on this problem, I just want to get 2 value from one radio button,
for example :

```
{{ Form::radio('jenjang','D1|6',true,['class' => 'with-gap']) }}
```

When I checked that radio button, I want to get "D1" and "6" without Java script, is it possible? How to do that in Laravel 5.5? Thanks in advance, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to get both values from the checkbox.

The 'jenjang' radio button can have the value 'D1'.

```
{{ Form::radio('jenjang','D1',true,['class' => 'with-gap']) }}
```

In your controller, get the value of the radio button and then also set the second value based on that:

```
$value1 = $request->input('jenjang');
if ($value1 == 'D1') {
    $value2 = 6;
}
```